# Error: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-2.0

I have the following action:

```
def index() {

  User.withNewTransaction {

   def user = User.get(params.userId)
   user.name = "test"
   user.save(flush:true)

   response.setContentType("image/gif")
   response.outputStream << PIXEL_BYTES_OF_A_GIF_IMAGE
   return
  }
}
```

When running, I sometimes get the following error:

```
Message
Executing action [index] of controller [test.TestController] caused exception: Runtime error executing action
Caused by
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [test.User#1]
```

Why does this error happen? I thought `withNewTransaction` would prevent this error.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645694/row-was-updated-or-deleted-by-another-transaction-or-unsaved-value-mapping-was

Comment: I am new in Grails can you exmplain this answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [pessimistic locking](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking)

Use:

```
User user = User.lock(params.userId)
```

or

```
User user = User.findById(params.userId, [lock: true])
```