# How to save parent and child in one call (Hibernate, JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know, that this question has been asked many times, but my case is different (e.g. [How to save parent and child in one shot (JPA & Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647672/how-to-save-parent-and-child-in-one-shot-jpa-hibernate))

I have DTOs:

```java
@Data
public class ExchangeRatesTableDto {
    private ExchangeRatesTableType table;
    private String no;
    private LocalDate tradingDate;
    private LocalDate effectiveDate;
    private List<ExchangeRateDto> rates;
}

@Data
public class ExchangeRateDto {
    private String currency;
    private String code;
    private Double mid;
    private Double bid;
    private Double ask;
}
```

And Entities:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = DatabaseNames.SCHEMA_NBP)
public class ExchangeRatesTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private ExchangeRatesTableType tableType;

    private String no;
    private LocalDate tradingDate;
    private LocalDate effectiveDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exchangeRatesTable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ExchangeRate> exchangeRates;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = DatabaseNames.SCHEMA_NBP)
public class ExchangeRate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_exchange_rates_table"))
    private ExchangeRatesTable exchangeRatesTable;

    private String currency;
    private String code;
    private Double mid;
    private Double bid;
    private Double ask;
}
```

I have two repositories too:

```java
public interface ExchangeRatesTableRepository extends JpaRepository<ExchangeRatesTable, UUID> {
}

public interface ExchangeRateRepository extends JpaRepository<ExchangeRate, UUID> {
}
```

And in controller I have this code:

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
ExchangeRatesTableDto table = exchangeRatesService.getTable(exchangeRatesTableType);
ExchangeRatesTable exchangeRatesTable = modelMapper.map(table, ExchangeRatesTable.class);
exchangeRatesTableRepository.save(exchangeRatesTable);
```

`exchangeRatesService` returns `ExchangeRatesTableDto` with childs.
ModelMapper returns:
[image: ExchangeRatesTable object]

But `save` method is not working:

```
Hibernate: /* insert model.ExchangeRatesTable */ insert into nbp.exchange_rates_table (effective_date, no, table_type, trading_date, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: /* insert model.ExchangeRate */ insert into nbp.exchange_rate (ask, bid, code, currency, exchange_rates_table_id, mid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-04-14 14:27:42.889  WARN 11404 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2021-04-14 14:27:42.889 ERROR 11404 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "exchange_rates_table_id" of relation "exchange_rate" violates not-null constraint
  Szczegóły: Failing row contains (f2a461e5-80ce-4837-aab9-a87919c978f8, null, null, BRL, real (Brazylia), 0.6658, null).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [exchange_rates_table_id" of relation "exchange_rate]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to manually set each and every `ExchangeRate` object with `ExchangeRatesTable` object, as you have `ExchangeRatesTable` setter method. then it will not be empty and get save in the DB as well.

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child1 = new Child();
child1.setParent(parent);
parent.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child1));
jpa.save(parent);
```

in your code you can iterate `ExchangeRateList` and set `ExchangeRatesTable` obj to all elements.

Comment: I forget about it. I added method to the `ExchangeRatesTable` class:
``` lang-java
    public void setExchangeRates(Set<ExchangeRate> exchangeRates) {
        exchangeRates.forEach(exchangeRate -> exchangeRate.setExchangeRatesTable(this));
        this.exchangeRates = exchangeRates;
    }
```
and replaced `@Data` with `@Getter` and `@Setter`, and it works.